# Estou com problemas para imprimir valores de database

Tags: python-3.x

estou tentando fazer imprimir o 'ok' na tela quando ele encontrar o valor '3' dentro de uma das keys do banco de dados.

```
>>> with dbm.open('data1.db','r') as user:
    user['0'] = '1'
    user['1'] = '2'
    user['2'] = '3'
    for i in user:
        if '3' in user[str(i)]:
            print('ok')


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#146>", line 3, in <module>
    if '3' in user[str(i)]:
  File "C:\Users\ThomasNote\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\dbm\dumb.py", line 148, in __getitem__
    pos, siz = self._index[key]     # may raise KeyError
KeyError: b"b'0'"




with dbm.open('data1.db','r') as user:
    for i in user:
        print(i.decode(), user[i].decode())

>>> 0 1
>>> 1 2
>>> 2 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo tipo de erro parece que a lista user que está tentando atualizar não está inicializada nas chaves correspondentes.

Entretanto, partindo da premissa de que a lista user foi inicializada e atualizada corretamente, tente o seguinte loop.

```
    for i in user:
     if (i=='3'):
      print('ok')
```

Comment: O problema é que deste jeito não aparece o 'ok' porque ele vai procurar entre os valores de 0 a 2(que são as chaves). Eu quero que o programa procure os valores que estão dentro das chaves

Comment: Acredito que não Thomas Caio. 
 Veja o 
[exemplo](https://goo.gl/jgtc1i)